# C++ AddressSanitizer with CMakeLists.txt results in asan errors

Tags: c++, cmake, address-sanitizer

Trying to use the [AddressSanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) tool (ASan) on my C++ project, I get a very verbose output full of `undefined reference to '__asan_report_store8'` and `undefined reference to '__asan_report_load8'`, and others like `__asan_stack_malloc_2`. My project is built with CMake, and I've added the following line to my CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_definitions(-fsanitize=address -g3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer)
```

following these ASan examples:

- [Example with makefile](https://gist.github.com/kwk/4171e37f4bcdf7705329)
- [Jason Turner quick intro video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MB6NPkB4YVs&t=469s)

Running the above makefile example I get the expected pretty output (which can also be seen in the video link). But for my project I'm getting a messy stack trace of those errors.

Notes:

- ubuntu 16.04
- I've set the environment variables `ASAN_OPTIONS=symbolize=1` and  `ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=/usr/lib/llvm-5.0/bin/llvm-symbolizer` in order to print the line numbers in the ASan output

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When compiling code to be run with one of the LLVM Sanitizers, you have to pass the `-fsanitize=...` flag to both the compiler and the linker. With CMake, you can do this by calling [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/command/target_link_libraries.html#overview):

```
target_link_libraries(MyTarget
  -fsanitize=address
)
```

Alternatively, if you aren't using modern CMake, you can do the same with the [`link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/command/link_libraries.html) command

Comment: Yes that does it! Now I can see my memory leaks :)

Comment: Any advice on getting the line numbers to print in the output? The config  I specified in above doesn't appear to work. And when I set `ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=/usr/lib/llvm-5.0/bin/llvm-symbolizer` as an `add_definitions` argument, cmake gives me an error that the path does not exist (when indeed it does, found with `which llvm-symbolizer`).

Comment: @BoltzmannBrain Have you set `ASAN_OPTIONS=symbolize=1` in environment?

Comment: @yugr yes, see the original post above. I set those options from the command line as `export ASAN_OPTIONS=symbolize=1` and then run the CMake steps.

Comment: CMake 3.13+ provides [target_link_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/target_link_options.html#target-link-options) as well.