# Enabling AddressSanitizer with Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, address-sanitizer

I have a project which built by cmake. I want to build it with AddressSanitizer to detect memory leaks. I added these lines into the CMakeLists.txt:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address")
set (CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG} -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address")
```

But it doesnt work some how (It doesnt show where i have memory leaks). I tested with a test application which definitely contains memory leaks, still nothing happened. Can somebody explain how should i do it ?

Comment: did you try -lasan ?

Comment: @OznOg where should i put it ?

Comment: in your link flags

Comment: @OznOg Should it be "set (CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG} -lasan -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address")" ?

Comment: Variable `CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG` has no special meaning for CMake. For set linker flags for executable target use [CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_CONFIG.html).

Comment: @Tsyvarev This does not work :(

Comment: If you build the project with `make` (after `cmake` call), you may run `make VERBOSE=1` for see command lines used for compiling and linking. Compare them with command lines suggested for use address-sanitizer.

Answer (score 5):

As an other option, it's possible to add sanitizers to target:

```
target_link_libraries(MyTarget PRIVATE -fsanitize=address)
```

Got from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50163972/8366223), tested with cmake 3.6

Answer (score 1):

try flags without `_DEBUG`.

```
    set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address")
    set (CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS} -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address")
```